# How to handle the Selenium Pop-up with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, alert, popupwindow

I tried several options to handle the Pop-up with Selenium and fill the field values. But it does not work with the below code.

**Selenium java code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginBox\"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys("xxx@yyy.com");
Thread.sleep(2000);

alert.accept();
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="content">
 <form class="ui form">
  <div class="field">
   <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <div view="horizontal" class="ui right corner labeled input">
     <div class="ui label label right corner">
      <i aria-hidden="true" class="asterisk icon">
      </i>
     </div><input name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Please enter email address" type="email" value="">
    </div>
   </div>
```

- How can I handle the Pop-up and fill the field?
- Also, in the end how do I close the alert window?

Comment: Could you share the image of the pop-up. To confirm that the field is present in a window or Pop-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pop-up is HTML element, not a modal dialog to use `driver.switchTo().alert()`.
To enter email you have to wait for the element, and for that `sleep` bad choice. Code below waiting for visibility of the `email` using [WebDriverWait](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp), it's best practice.
Also, not a good practice to use `//*[@id=\"loginBox\"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div` like selectors. You can find some helpful information about best practice for selectors [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator).

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

// ...

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loginBox\"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div")).click();

WebElement email = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("Email")));
email.sendKeys("xxx@yyy.com");
email.submit();
```